# Set to one column by binding different color - DataGrid

Tags: wpf, mvvm, datagrid

I have a class X there are some data:

```
    private string yyy;

    public string YYY
    {
        get { return yyy; }
        set
        {
            yyy= value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("YYY");
        }
    }

    private string color;
    [Browsable(false)]
    public string Color
    {
        get { return color; }
        set
        {
            color = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Color");
        }
    }
```

I have ObservableCollection that keeps a list of class X

```
public ObservableCollection<X> xxx{ get; set; }
```

The list Contracting to DataGrid by binding as follows:

```
    <DataGrid x:Name="XXXX" ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="True">
                </DataGrid>
```

The list is in the DataContext of the DataGrid,

I want the text of the first column in each row will be on color that I have of the class data? I will do converter that change from string to color but how do I define this in xmal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [`DataGridTemplateColumn`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridtemplatecolumn.celltemplate%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
   <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="FirstName" >
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding FirstName}" Foreground="{Binding Color}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
       <DataGridTextColumn Header="LastName" Binding="{Binding LastName}"></DataGridTextColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

The conversion from string to color is implicit. 
I know it is not strict MVVM but I would not lose sleep about having the Color property of type Color.

Comment: When I write {Binding FirstName} it will take from a list in the order because it does not display data when I did so ..

Comment: I think you want to write  {Binding YYY} (the name of your property to display) and have the ItemsSource="{Binding YourProperty}", the code in my answer is just an example.

Comment: I know i write yyy and it not display the data

Comment: My guess is that the itemssource is not wired up properly then.
1) Your viewmodel should be the datacontext of the Window/UC
2) Then ItemsSource="{Binding xxx}" will bind to the propperty in the viewmodel.